# How to involve a web service method with 4 String params by Spring integration outbound gateway?

Tags: jaxb, spring-integration, spring-ws

I have setup the gateway and service, but the web method is not a wrapped object but just 4 Strings.

JAXB raised the error

"javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]"

```
public interface WebMethodGateway {

    @Gateway
    @Payload("#args[0] + #args[1] + #args[2] + #args[3]")
    public Response invoke(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, String arg4);

}
```

integration.xml

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="outboundGateway"
    request-channel="requestChannel" 
    reply-channel="responseChannel"
    uri="http://localhost:8080/Service?wsdl"
    message-sender="messageSender" 
    marshaller="marshaller"
    unmarshaller="marshaller"/>

<bean id="messageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="5000"/>
    <property name="readTimeout" value="10000"/>
</bean>


<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="responseChannel"/>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" context-path="myProject.ws.bean" />

<int:gateway id="webMethodGateway" 
    default-request-channel="requestChannel"
    default-reply-channel="responseChannel"
    service-interface="myProject.ws.gateway.WebMethodGateway" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it isn't `4 Strings`, it is single concatenated String :

```
@Payload("#args[0] + #args[1] + #args[2] + #args[3]")
```

Another concern.

`<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` is for Web Services, SOAP. Therefore XML.
Right JaxB produces an XML for you, but it does that exactly for domain entities, not simple strings.

You can bypass JaxB with String `payload`, but that really must be an XML representing `<soap:body>` content.